# Speed up filter of large list in Kotlin

Tags: optimization, kotlin

I've got an `ArrayList` with about 4000 `Pair<Int,Int>`s (points on a grid).
At one point I need to get the points in a certain range of x and y coordinates.

My code so far is:

```
val points: ArrayList = // ...

val xRange: IntRange = x: Int - spacingX: Int .. x: Int + spacingX: Int
val yRange: IntRange = y: Int - spacingY: Int .. y: Int + spacingY: Int

val nearPoints: ArrayList<Point<Int, Int>> = points.filter { xRange.contains(it.first) && yRange.contains(it.second) }
```

It is considerably faster than iterating over the entire list, but I hoped to further speed up the process.

Is it possible to get the `nearPoints: ArrayList` faster, through another construct? I've read about `Sequence`, but it seems to be better for multiple operations, rather than pure filtering.

Comment: I tried to to filter parts of the list (size of test list 1,000,000 elements) concurrently using coroutines, but unfornately there is no speedup but actually a slow down compared to how you do it now. so I think your way of doing it, already is really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `ArrayList` guarantees constant time complexity O(1) (per accessed element) when iterating and since `contains` of `IntRange` already makes a range check

```
override fun contains(value: Int): Boolean = first <= value && value <= last
```

and does not search for a particular element, I don't think you can further speed it up.

Note: It would be more idiomatic to use `in` instead of `contains`.

Comment: Sorry, but it is O(N), where N is the size of the list to iterate the list (you need to check every item from there). What exactly do you mean by O(1)?

Comment: Thx! I clarified it!

Answer (score 1):

The `sequence` in Kotlin makes the process work lazily. At the JVM level, you will have a class like `Iterable` that would use an Iterator from the ArrayList to apply the filter.

The best is to profile the code on real data (but 4000 items is probably not many at all) and see where are the bottlenecks.

You need to place the points into ArrayList. It means you do not need the laziness at all. I would vote to use the `.filter { .. }` *inline* function on the ArrayList. The lambda is inlined into the code in that case, there is no method call per element. Check the bytecode. Probably, you may even replace Ranges with comparisons too.

Should you need more speed - you may try to replace ArrayList> with primitive types, e.g. use `IntArray` or `LongArray` (you may encode two `Int`'s as one `Long`. But please, profile existing code before